# I want to restrict a user to access data of other users through API

Tags: javascript, c#, api, token, access-token

I have implemented token based authentication and authorization. I am storing the value of token in session. How to restrict a user to access the data of other users if user gets the token. I am passing token only in header. So if user is able to get the token value anyhow so he can access any API for any user. I am calling apis in jQuery.

Comment: This is kind of the point of implicit authentication.    The user trusts their browser with their token.   If you hide it in any way the browser wont be able to use it.

Comment: Just try not to pass sensitive information in query parameters - that is common practice because of loggers and other related things on server side

Comment: so... one token gives you access to the whole API ? why are you not limiting a token's accessibility to specific user data and only that ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you save the value of the token in a session? That doesn't make sense, since your authorization becomes session dependent, not token dependent. If you exchange password and username for token, don't use sessions as the token becomes redundant - you are authorizing the user through your session cookie.

Also, this is the idea of the token - to be working just for an hour (most services use this amount of time for the token life). So if you are not implementing an OAuth authentication strategy, why use tokens in the first place? And if you do, why use sessions? I think you are mixing different approaches here.

Comment: I am getting the value of token in c# by passing username and password and i am calling API in jQuery .so i am storing token in session so that i can use in jquery